# Как преобразовать unicode в utf-8

Tags: python

Есть слово `Авторизация` в unicode

```
'\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f '
```

Какими только кодерами не пробова - не получается его преобразовать в норм utf-8

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю что должно получиться.

Comment: '\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f '
эту хрень надо декодировать

Comment: У вас проблемы со шрифтами. у меня это слово печатается нормально)

Comment: Откуда вы взяли это слово в таком виде и куда именно вы хотите получить utf-8?

Answer (score 3):

По умолчанию для метода `encode` используется `utf-8`:

```
>>> s = u'\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f '
>>> t = s.encode()
>>> t
b'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb2\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f '
>>> t.decode()
'Авторизация '
```

Comment: пардон, но он возвращает ту же самую строку

Comment: https://snag.gy/BXJids.jpg

Comment: `>>> s = u'\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0448\u043b\u0430 \u0443\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0448\u043d\u043e'`
`>>> t = s.encode().decode()`
`>>> t
'Авторизация прошла успешно'`

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3

Можно докодировать до байтов, потом декодировать:

```
>>> test = '\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f'

>>> test.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u0410\\u0432\\u0442\\u043e\\u0440\\u0438\\u0437\\u0430\\u0446\\u0438\\u044f'

>>> test.encode('unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape')
'Авторизация'
```

---

### Python 2

Юникод с Python 2 и ещё на Windows - это убиться можно!

Приведенный код обеспечивает одинаковый вывод на Linux и в консоли Windows

В консоли Windows должна стоять кодировка `cp65001`. Это можно изменить командой: `chcp 65001`. Также для консоли следует выбрать векторный шрифт, например consolas.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os
import codecs

if sys.platform == "win32":
    class UniStream(codecs.StreamWriter):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.fileno = args[0].fileno()
            codecs.StreamWriter.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        def write(self, text):
            os.write(self.fileno, text.encode("utf_8") if isinstance(text, unicode) else text)

    sys.stdout = UniStream(sys.stdout)
    sys.stderr = UniStream(sys.stderr)

print sys.stdout.encoding
test = '\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f'
print test
test_decoded = test.decode('unicode_escape')
print test_decoded
test_utf8 = test_decoded.encode('utf-8')
print test_utf8
```

Linux:

```
[root@centos ~]# python unicodedecode2.py
UTF-8
\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f
Авторизация
Авторизация
```

Windows:

```
C:\Projects\StackOverflow\Python>py -2 unicodedecode2.py
cp65001
\u0410\u0432\u0442\u043e\u0440\u0438\u0437\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f
Авторизация
Авторизация
```

Comment: https://snag.gy/BXJids.jpg

Comment: @Radzhab А какая версия Python? Я тестировал на 3.6